# Double Instrumentation error on clover plugin

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, clover

I'm using clover maven plugin for a multi module project. I'm experiencing a CloverException upon running the instrument goal for clover. It's displaying "Double Instrumentation detected" appears to have already been instrumented by Clover. I've no idea how this is happening and I've searched on google about it and still got no clue what to do. Has anyone seen this error before and perhaps solved it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Double instrumentation detected" means that your sources have been already instrumented by Clover and you're trying to instrument them once again.

First, please check if you don't run Clover's instrumentation twice in your build (e.g. clover2:setup + clover2:instrument).

Second, please check if you don't have any sources instrumented by Clover committed accidentally to a version control system. You can recognize such files by the "/* $$ This file has been instrumented by Clover" comment present in a source file.

Comment: Thanks Marek. Correct me if I'm wrong because I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, clover2:setup and clover2:instrument are the same? I've used these maven commands for my project:  clover2:clean clover2:setup clover2:instrument test clover2:clover.

Comment: Yes, clover2:setup and clover2:instrument are very similar. Both perform code instrumentation. The difference between them is as follows: 
 - clover2:setup instruments code in Maven's default build life cycle; which means that you'll find instrumented classes / jars in a standard location; therefore it's not recommended to use clover2:setup together with "install" or "deploy" (to avoid publishing instrumented code)
 - clover2:instrument forks a parallel build life cycle; thanks to this in a single build both normal and instrumented classes/jars are produced; jars have '-clover' suffix